# Java: Displaying all elements from an array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods, return

I have created a String method that uses a loop to return all data elements of an object. The problem is, since it is a return statement, it will go through the loop once and then exit the method once the return statement has been executed.

I have looked over StackOverflow and the internet and have not been able to assist myself into figuring out this problem.

Code:

```
public String display()
{
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) //assume count has the value of 3
    {
        return "Name: "+item[i].getName(); //this is the issue; only loops once, then exits method
        //also assume that an object item[] has been initialised with 3 positions
    }
}
```

Comment: **Don't** return inside for loop

Comment: `return` means "end this method, *now*" - the behavior observed is only fitting.

Comment: Can you show a little more of what you are trying to do?  What do you mean "return all data elements of an object"?  How do you know there are 3 of them?  What is `item`?  It may be that there is a better answer; for example, if `item` is an array and you want to make it into a string, you can use `Arrays.toString(item)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code was not working is that it was returning as soon as you reached the statement in the loop. Functions have return values, and in java, the return "x" statement returns the value "x" to the previous statement.

Say you wrote in your code

`entireArray = display();`

When that statement is reached during execution, the display method is called. The code then jumps to the display method. When the display method is called, it jumps into your loop. At the first line, it sees `return "Name: "+item[i].getName();` This gets the name of the first item, appending it behind "Name: ". The function then returns to the previous line, entireArray = display();

Basically, display() is then replaced with the return value of the function. If you want to make sure everything is included, model your code off of something like this:

```
public String display() {
    String total = "Name: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        total += item[i].getName();
    }
    return total;
}
```

This makes sure that every item's name in the "item" array is returned.

I would recommend that you read up a bit about call stacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack. This will help explain how functions return values, and why your original code did not work.

Answer (score 1):

you are returning within loop, so as soon as it executes that `return` statement it will return from method without further iterating through loop

use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) content and at the end (after loop) return built `String`

Comment: It might be worth explaining to op why they're facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that people encounter with the `return` statement. In situations such as this I generally create a new String and have it return that. For example:

```
public String display()
{
     String s = "Name: ";
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         s = s + item.getName();
     }

     return s;

}
```

That way, you are actively adding onto a new string that you plan to return later. This method has proved extremely helpful for me, not only with strings but also with integers and ArrayLists. Because return statements result in the exiting of your code, you are going to want to try and keep them at the end of your methods unless you have some specific reason for having the return statement earlier in the method.

Comment: using StringBuilder is the best way instead of concatenating

Comment: @ImmerAllein In the original post there is a return statement inside a loop. I think the easiest answer it is the best in this context